# Delete button to remove An ID - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that will add some text with a checkbox vertically, like a To Do list.

This works fine, and I tried to add a 'delete' button to remove individual entries but I'm getting nowhere,I tried writing the 'delete' code myself but it seems completely useless, any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
       Enter What To Do<input id='userInput' size=60> <button onClick='userSubmit()'>Submit</button><BR><P>
       <div id='result'></div>
       <button onClick='userDelete()'>X</button>
```

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function userSubmit() {
var UI=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+='<input type="checkbox"> '+UI+'<br>';}   </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>function userDelete(){
    var UI=document.getElementById('result');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML-='' '+UI+';}</script>
```

updated in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/64u4B/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle and share please?

Comment: I think what he tries to do is to create a list of things by adding them to the "result" and pressing submit. They also have a checkbox. By selecting a checkbox and pressing delete the selected checkbox and the text text to it should be deleted. -> I think this wont work without having seperate id's or names for the input fields. I would suggest an counter while creating them

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
function addItem() {
var value = document.getElementById('userInput').value,
    taskListContainer = document.getElementById('task-list');
var html = '<article id="task-item">' +
                '<input type="checkbox">' +
                 '<section class="task-content">' + value + '</section> <br />' +
                '<button class="delete-btn" title="Delete tasks">DELETE</button>' +
    '</article>';

taskListContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

}

```
var deleteItem = function(event){
    var isDeleteBtnClicked = event.target.className === 'delete-btn';

   if(isDeleteBtnClicked){
      var taskElement = event.target.parentNode;
      document.getElementById('task-list').removeChild(taskElement);
  }
```

}

```
document.getElementById('task-list').addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
document.getElementById('add-task').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/64u4B/10/

Comment: I used this code but it still behaves as it did before, the delete button is doing nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my for providing this as a seperate answer, but unable to comment due to lack of rep.

Can you provide a js fiddle of your work so we can all see clearly what your doing?

Edit and Rememberance: There is a site TodoMVC it provides a vanilla JS example of what you're trying to achieve. [Vanilla JS Todo](http://todomvc.com/vanilla-examples/vanillajs/).

Comment: I tried adding my code for the delete button but it wouldn't work at all on jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

If the Delete button is created dynamically through javascript, this may get complex,

But simply a delete function should be like this

```
function delete(id)
{
 var elem = document.getElementById('id');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
}
```

Note you should refer its parent node before removing an element.